# Silverlight 4.0 - Deploying the XAP via a custom installer and configure it for OOB + Elevated permissions

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, blend, silverlight-oob

Is it possible to deploy a XAP using a custom installer (much like deploying a desktop app), and configure it to run as OOB with Elevated permissions?

Bottomline is, when the app is started, it should run in Elevated permissions + OOB, with out any user intervention at all after the installation.

Comment: Excellent question, I know where you are going with this, but wondering what kind of activities, you will be doing with the Elevated permissions...

Comment: To leverage OOB features, like Communicating with other components, say for generating a PDF? lol

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty easier than I thought.

You can edit the metadata file in the isolated storage where the xap is copied for OOB scenario, and point the index.html to the xap path.

http://debuggingblog.com/wp/2009/07/17/silverlight-3-outofbrowseroob-explained-and-how-to-host-any-xap-package-by-modifying-the-metadata/